# netCore 2.2 webApi - нет доступа к статическим файлам (wwwroot) при запуске в Docker контейнере в режиме release

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Столкнулся в проблемой- JS клиент для SignalR не доступен на Production, хотя при отладке (режим Debug) все работало локально и в Docker и локально.
Т.е. обращаясь к Index.html в ответ получаю Not found.

Для понимания в чем дело создал новый проект webApi c Docker (Linux) и проблема повторилась.

Все работает нормально если запускаю так:

1. Локально (kestrel) режим Debug
2. Локально (kestrel) режим Relise
3. Docker (kestrel) режим Debug

И только если Docker режим Relise, то доступа НЕТ.
Контейнер запущен нормально, внутри контейнера папка wwwroot со всем содержимым присутствует.

Включил Cors для теста, но все также.

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["StaticFilesInDocker/StaticFilesInDocker.csproj", "StaticFilesInDocker/"]
RUN dotnet restore "StaticFilesInDocker/StaticFilesInDocker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/StaticFilesInDocker"
RUN dotnet build "StaticFilesInDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "StaticFilesInDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "StaticFilesInDocker.dll"]
```

Startup

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
                {
                    policy
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors("default");
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Вывод в консоль

Debug локально

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: F:\C#\NetCore\StaticFilesInDocker\StaticFilesInDocker
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Docker (Release)

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {0e8fc511-16cd-41b5-99a2-be9e1f3304c1} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.



        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get()
        {
            var wwwrootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            return wwwrootPath;
        }

Выводит /app/wwwroot
```

Comment: А что прога при запуске в консоли пишет? Там должен быть написан путь до webroot

Comment: Добавил вывод в консоль

Comment: var wwwrootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath; Выводит /app/wwwroot

Comment: Теперь посмотрите, есть ли в /app/wwwroot искомый файл.

Comment: Да есть, зашел во внутрь контейнера "docker exec -it b871495375e9 bash" и нашел /app/wwwroot/Index.html

Comment: Причем при обращении к нему (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development) в консоль пишется что запрос есть а в ответ 404 NotFound

Comment: То-есть доступ до контроллеров есть api/values. А Статические файлы не выдаются.

Comment: Хм, попробуйте-ка поиграться с регистром символов

Comment: В другом браузере заработало! Походу что-то с Chrome. Спасибо за участие!!! Благодаря вашим комментария понял что надо копать не в сторону кода.